# Using XlLineStyle as an object C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a code that draws a line around a cell in an Excel sheet depending on a value in a string, `border`:

```
    if (border != null)
    {
        //can be one or serval of below
        if (border.Contains("Bottom"))
            workSheet.Cells[i, j].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        if (border.Contains("Right"))
            workSheet.Cells[i, j].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        if (border.Contains("Left"))
            workSheet.Cells[i, j].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        if (border.Contains("Top"))
            workSheet.Cells[i, j].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
    }
```

Now I want to add a new variable, `string linetype`, that determines the line:

```
        if (linetype == "Double")
            lineobject = XlLineStyle.xlDouble;
```

So that I can write:

```
workSheet.Cells[i, j].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = lineobject;
```

Adding the string is of course easy. But I don't know how I can define the `lineobject` so that I can use a specific linetype later on without having to rewrite the first part of the code here for each line type I would like to use for all of the four locations of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to define custom border (in Excel UI you also need separately select line, color and width), but LineStyle/lineobject can be easily assinged to some variable as

```
var cell = worksheet.Cells[2, 2];
var border = cell.Borders;

var myborderstyle = XlLineStyle.xlDash;
var myborderweight = 4d;

border.LineStyle = myborderstyle;  <-- set specific linetype
border.Weight = myborderweight;    <-- set specific width
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, except for the line: border.Weight: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Weight' and no accessible extension method 'Weight' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Edit: same goes for `LineStyle`

Comment: What is "string" there in your code and what version do you do? The `Borders.Weight` Property is there, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.borders.weight?view=excel-pia, same for https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.borders.linestyle?view=excel-pia

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had a string named border in the code (which I posted above) and forgot about it. It works, thanks!